# Deleting a pattern from a file and appending it to the end?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a log file which have contents like below:

```
 #SOME MORE DATA 
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01#
 #SOME MORE DATA     
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-B-01#
 #SOME MORE DATA    
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-C-01#
 #SOME MORE DATA     
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-D-01#
 #SOME MORE DATA    
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-B-01#
 #SOME MORE DATA
```

I want to delete all such lines from the file and append it to the end
 of the file in a way such that it becomes like :

```
#ALL the remaining data at top
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-A-01#
SWEs-elmPCI-B-01#
SWEs-elmPCI-C-01#
SWEs-elmPCI-D-01#
SWEs-elmPCI-B-01#
```

I am thinking of using `sed -n '/These*/{n;p}'` but still unable to achieve the result.

NOTE : SOME MORE DATA means more content in the file and these types of lines could be any where in the file

```
These switches don't have latest images :
SWEs-elmPCI-B-01#
```

Comment: Can't you just create a file that begins with "these switches" and then append the output of a sed that strips that line to that same file? `echo "These switches don't have latest images :" > newfile ; sed '/^These switches.*/d' >> newfile`

Comment: This data is just a part of whole data i need all the data in the original file with this change

Comment: @munish `cat newfile >> oldfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -ne '/^These/{n;w tempfile
d;};p' < oldfile > newfile
echo "These switches don't have latest images :" >> newfile
cat tempfile >> newfile
```

One could use the hold space instead of a temporary file:

```
sed -ne '/^These/{n;H;d;};p;${x;s/^/These switches don'"'"'t have latest images :/;p;}' < oldfile > newfile
```

This will fail, however, if the file ends with one of the "These switches" blocks, rather than with "SOME MORE DATA". The reason is that the last command `${x;....p;}` is executed only if the last line hasn't be deleted before by a
`d` command. If you want to avoid temporary files, it's probably better to use perl or python. It's certainly more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Uwe for help, i will try to use this but creating files for every task and deleting them seems awkward.I wish i could use some kind of buffer like expect does.